# Why is the following statement legal in C but not in Java?

Tags: java, c, ternary-operator

Why is the following statement legal in C but not in Java?

```
int k = 1;
(10 < 20) ? k++ : k--;
```

Comment: Because Java is not C

Comment: Neither of the proposed dupes addresses the OP's question. The problem they address deals with using non-expression statements on the RHS. The OP's problem is caused by the absence of the LHS.

Comment: @flakes: Make that an answer after this is reopened.

Answer (score 5):

This is because in C all expressions can be made into expression-statements by adding a semicolon `;`.

In Java not all expressions can be made into expression statements. They must be assignment expressions, use postfix/prefix operators, be method invocations, or new expressions. [See more here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html)

Further, a ternary operator in Java requires that each operand be a non void expression and the value returned must be assigned.